# In what episode of TNG is it established that Vulcan ships have no weapons?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

In what episode of TNG is it established that Vulcan ships have no weapons? Any other information on the Vulcan commitment to peacefulness and pacifism are welcome.

Comment: Just by a cursory search, I was able to find [Vulcan ships](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_starship_classes) with weapons. Are you referring to a particular class or type of Vulcan ships?

Comment: If Vulcan ships had no weapons, how on earth would they manage to [say hello](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_Hello)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely remembering
ST:TNG Unification Part 2
from http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/207.htm

The Bar Scene with the Ferengi weapons dealer...

> RIKER: Commander William Riker, USS Enterprise.
> OMAG: Am I supposed to stand up and salute?
> RIKER: We're investigating the disappearance of a Vulcan ship.
> OMAG: Well you've got the wrong Ferengi. I never trade in Vulcan ships.
> RIKER: We know that you're involved.
> OMAG: Who would want a Vulcan ship? Vulcans are pacifists. I deal in warships. Can somebody get me a napkin?
> RIKER: Who would want a Vulcan ship?
> OMAG: Hypothetically speaking?
> RIKER: Hypothetically speaking.
> OMAG: I never learned to speak hypothetical.

On Vulcan pacifism
ST:TOS The Savage Curtain
transcript from http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/77.htm

> SURAK: In my time on Vulcan, we also faced these same alternatives. We'd suffered devastating wars which nearly destroyed our planet. Another was about to begin. We were torn. But out of our suffering some of us found the discipline to act. We sent emissaries to our opponents to propose peace. The first were killed, but others followed. Ultimately we achieved peace, which has lasted since then.
> KIRK: Circumstances were different then, Surak.
> SURAK: The face of war has never changed, Captain. Surely it is more logical to heal than kill.
> KIRK: I'm afraid that kind of logic doesn't apply here.
> SURAK: That is precisely why we should not fight.
> KIRK: My ship is at stake.
> SURAK: I will not harm others, Captain.
> SPOCK: His convictions are most profound in this matter, Captain.
> KIRK: So are mine, Spock. If I believed that there was a peaceful way out of this
> SURAK: The risk will be mine alone. If I fail, you lose nothing. After all, I'm no warrior.
> SPOCK: The captain knows that I have fought at his side before and will do so now, if need be. However, I too, am a Vulcan, bred to peace. Let him attempt it.
> KIRK: You saw how treacherously they acted.
> SURAK: Oh, yes. But perhaps it's our belief in peace that is actually being tested.
> KIRK: I have no authority over you. You may do as you think best.

Comment: The quote from TNG doesn't state that Vulcan ships don't carry weapons, it merely states that the Vulcan ships at that time aren't dedicated warships.

Comment: @KeithMorrison the original question is a false premise likely based on the episode quoted.

Answer (score -1):

False they do have weapons. Although classified as science vessels, they can serve as war ships.  https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Suurok_class

Comment: At the moment this is close to a link-only answer, could you [edit] in some supporting references?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/183667)